# force client disconnect from server with socket.io and nodejs

Tags: socket.io

Is there any way to disconnect a client with SocketIO, and literally close the connection? So if someone is connected to my server, and I want to close the connection between them and my server, how would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 167, accepted):

**Edit: This is now possible**

[You can now simply call `socket.disconnect()` on the server side](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/issues/47).

**My original answer:**

This is not possible yet.

If you need it as well, vote/comment on [this issue](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/issues/47).

Comment: So I'm doing that, and it does force the client to disconnect, unfortunately it appears that the client simply reconnects immediately.  Am I misunderstanding what is going on, or is that the expected behaviour?

Comment: @kybernetikos Yes, I would expect this - the client can choose what to do with their own after all. Often, you want to kick the other side from the *current* connection, say because of an auth timeout - a reconnect after this would probably even be desireable.

Comment: So do you know of any way of telling the client 'go away and I really mean it'?  I'm thinking from the point of view of determining that a client is behaving badly and not wanting them using up resource on my server.

Comment: @kybernetikos No, you can't do that (generally). If you are programming the client side though, you can of course implement any logic you want, e.g. stop it from reconnecting. If not, have to repeatedly kick the users, or if really necessary, resort to standard blocking techniques; the lower level these are implemented (e.g. `iptables`), the more resources you will save. In most cases, simply kicking the client should be sufficient though, since socketio does not connect that rapidly, and if somebody really wants to DoS you, they have other ways anyway (e.g. downloading pages from you).

Comment: hi @nh2, I have also want to disconnect socket from node.js (server side), but problem is How do I get socket from IO.Sockets of my particular/specific user? Or I have to store this socket in some variable or array?

Comment: @ManishSapkal If your "user" is some arbitrary object you define in your application, then sure, you have to store what socket(s) belong to a user the first time you associate them.

Comment: thanks @nh2 for reply. Now I am facing very strange problem. I have written following code on server side. io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) { console.log('A socket with sessionID connected! ' + socket.id); socket.on('disconnect', function() { console.log('socket.on.disconnect ');      });
     socket.on('error', function(err) {
     });
     socket.on('message', function(data) { 
           }); }); With above code my 'disconnected' event fire after 'connect' event? I don't know where is the mistek I have done. do you get any clue?

Comment: @ManishSapkal You should probably open a new question for that, it does not fit well into comments.

Comment: does this have a callback function or does it syncronously disconnect? I cannot find anything in socket.io docs...

Comment: @nh2 can you add a basic snippet demonstrating how to call socket.disconnect()? Can we call it in a socket message event listener?

Comment: @Akshay 10 years later, I am no longer using socket.io; best asked in their forums or issue tracker.

Answer (score 19):

`socket.disconnect()` can be used only on the client side, not on the server side.

`Client.emit('disconnect')` triggers the disconnection event on the server, but does not effectively disconnect the client. The client is not aware of the disconnection.

So the question remain : how to force a client to disconnect from server side ?

Comment: You don't have to call `Client.emit('disconnect')` manually anymore with recent socket.io versions, there is now a server-side `socket.disconnect()` (see my answer).

Comment: I agree, this answer is no longer valid, because now the `socket.disconnect()` can be used at the server side too.

Comment: @VassilisBarzokas What if I want a callback and pass some parameters to the callback after the `disconnect()` function is finished?

Comment: create a agreed set of messages where one party informs the other party that they wish to disconnect, then do what you need to do, and _then_ actually disconnect.

Answer (score 12):

Any reason why you can't have the server emit a message to the client that makes it call the disconnect function?

On client:

```
socket.emit('forceDisconnect');
```

On Server:

```
socket.on('forceDisconnect', function(){
    socket.disconnect();
});
```

Comment: Because client-side code can never be relied upon to function exactly as you want. Users can easily modify it.

Answer (score 12):

Checking this morning it appears it is now:

```
socket.close()
```

https://socket.io/docs/client-api/#socket-close

Comment: no more valid, any new update ?

Comment: @KoLynn it's valid I've just tried and it works. 
at least for v4.

https://socket.io/docs/v4/client-api/#socketclose

Answer (score 5):

For those who found this on google - there is a solution for this right now:

`Socket.disconnect()` kicks the client (server-side). No chance for the client to stay connected :)

Comment: How Do I find socket of user who is disconnected on server?

Comment: Manish: Listen for the socket's `disconnect` event to find out whether it has disconnected. Can also be the `close` event, I'm not quite sure. See socket.io's documentation for further information on this.

Answer (score 5):

This **didn't work** for me:

```
`socket.disconnect()`
```

This **did work** for me:

```
socket.disconnect(true)
```

Handing over `true` will close the underlaying connection to the client and not just the namespace the client is connected to [Socket IO Documentation](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/blob/b754cff2b415a8cbbf0f23c61824bcc69b078430/docs/API.md#socketdisconnectclose).

---

An example use case: Client did connect to web socket server with invalid access token (access token handed over to web socket server with connection params). Web socket server notifies the client that it is going to close the connection, because of his invalid access token:

```
// (1) the server code emits
socket.emit('invalidAccessToken', function(data) {
    console.log(data);       // (4) server receives 'invalidAccessTokenEmitReceived' from client
    socket.disconnect(true); // (5) force disconnect client 
});

// (2) the client code listens to event
// client.on('invalidAccessToken', (name, fn) => { 
//     // (3) the client ack emits to server
//     fn('invalidAccessTokenEmitReceived');
// });
```

Answer (score 4):

Assuming your socket's named socket, use:

```
socket.disconnect()
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work. I'm trying to close the connection to a specific client from the server-side.

Answer (score 3):

In my case I wanted to tear down the underlying connection in which case I had to call `socket.disconnect(true)` as you can see is needed from the [source here](https://github.com/Automattic/socket.io/blob/master/lib/socket.js#L446)

Answer (score 2):

`client._onDisconnect()` should work

Comment: This works perfectly..
Im maintain my own mapping to clients..
using that mapping ... easily disconnecting clients.. cheers

Answer (score 2):

I'm using `client.emit('disconnect')` + `client.removeAllListeners()` for connected client for ignore all events after disconnect

Answer (score 2):

To disconnect socket forcefully from server side

```
socket.disconnect(true)
```

**OR**

To disconnect socket by client side event

On client:

```
socket.emit('forceDisconnect');
```

On Server:

```
socket.on('forceDisconnect', function(){
    socket.disconnect(true);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Socket.io uses the EventEmitter pattern to disconnect/connect/check heartbeats so you could do.  `Client.emit('disconnect');`

Answer (score 0):

I am using on the client side `socket.disconnect();`

```
client.emit('disconnect') didnt work for me
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do `socket = undefined` in erase which socket you have connected. So when want to connected do socket(url)

So it will look like this

```
const socketClient = require('socket.io-client');

let socket;

// Connect to server
socket = socketClient(url)

// When want to disconnect
socket = undefined;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have using the socket client on React Native app, when I called `socketIOClient.disconnect()` this disconnects from the server but when I connect to the socket again the previous events were connected again, and the below code works for me by removing all existing events and disconnecting socket conneciton.

```js
socketIOClient.removeAllListeners();
socketIOClient.disconnect(true);
```

Answer (score -2):

Add new socket connections to an array and then when you want to close all - loop through them and disconnect. (server side)

```
var socketlist = [];

   io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
        socketlist.push(socket);  
        //...other code for connection here..
   });


    //close remote sockets
    socketlist.forEach(function(socket) {        
        socket.disconnect();                      
    });
```

Answer (score -2):

use :

> socket.Disconnect() //ok

do not use :

> socket.disconnect()