# Socket.io-client on node.js works only once

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I want to create new sockei.io-client on the server side (with node.js) every time when server gets request. But the code below works only once and then sockei.io-client does't response. Application doesn't stop, no errors.

```
var http = require("http");


http.createServer(function(request, response) {

var io = require('socket.io-client'); 
localSocket = io.connect('http://localhost:9876/');
localSocket.on('connect', function (data) {
                         response.writeHead(200, {"Content-type": "text/plain"});
                         response.write(data.name);
                         response.end();
                         localSocket.disconnect();
       });


}).listen(8080);
```

Socket.io server (on localhost:9876) works well - it serves clients with names (which is

```
 data.name
```

in the code here).

What is wrong?

**UPDATE:** The problem is solved by myself: To run multiple connection for socket.io-client need to add connect option {'force new connection': true}, like that:

```
localSocket = io.connect('http://localhost:9876/', {'force new connection': true});
```

Thank you!

Comment: Thanks that you have updated your answer. Instead of update, I would suggest to add it as answer

Comment: `force new connection` has been changed to `forceNew` as of socket.io 1.0

Answer (score 0):

> For those who found this on google - there is a solution for this right now:
>
> Socket.disconnect() kicks the client (server-side). No chance for the client to stay connected :)

[force client disconnect from server with socket.io and nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5048231/force-client-disconnect-from-server-with-socket-io-and-nodejs)

I think you just have to remove the disconnect() line.

Comment: well, i'm aware what disconnect() do. I want to create new socket.io-client and connect to the server every time i receive http request.