# Destroy socket.io connection when disconnect

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io, handlebars.js

i'm having an issue where a user disconnects from socket.io and the instances remains active, including all event listeners.

Both examples below is partial code of my progress due to hundreds of rows. But the issue remains with this code.

app.js example:

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    routes = require('./routes/index'),
    server = require('http').createServer(app);

io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

app.engine('handlebars', exphbs({ defaultLayout: 'main' }));
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');

app.use('/', routes);

server.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log('listening on *:3000');
});

module.exports = app;
```

index.js route example:

```
var express = require('express'),
    router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('home', {
        title: 'Home'
    });

    setupSocket(req);
});

function setupSocket(req) {
    io.on('connection', function(socket) {
        console.log('connected')
    });
}

module.exports = router;
```

This will result in:

First connection:

```
connected
```

Second connection:

```
connected
connected
```

Third connection:

```
connected
connected
connected
```

And so on. This will continue on page reload, in a new tab, in a new browser or anything else until i restart the node server.

In my code i'm posting data from client side to a mongo database and due the the issue above, the request will post multiple copies of the same data.

So the question is, how do i prevent the instance to remain active after a user has left the page?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5048231/force-client-disconnect-from-server-with-socket-io-and-nodejs

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately this does not solve the issue, i run`socket.on('disconnect', function() { socket.disconnect(); });` But when i reload the page it still keep stacking 'connected' in the console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said on every connection or refresh you are getting multiple`connected` strings outputs, that's because you are attaching socket.io listeners on each request. This is how you should attach the `connected` listener on your socket.io:

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    routes = require('./routes/index'),
    server = require('http').createServer(app);

io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

app.engine('handlebars', exphbs({ defaultLayout: 'main' }));
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');

app.use('/', routes);

// Your listener should be outside your routes
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    console.log('connected')
});

server.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log('listening on *:3000');
});

module.exports = app;
```

And on your index.js just remove the setUp function:

```
var express = require('express'),
    router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('home', {
        title: 'Home'
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: How would you open a socket only on a certain URL then?

Comment: Why would you want that? You want your socket server running every time

Comment: My socket starts another function, so I only wanted it to register a socket connection on a certain URL. I was putting it under the URL request block but am having the same problem as OP.

Comment: But that's front end specific. On your website whenever you are on a certain URL you create the connection to the socket server. Your socket server has nothing to do with URLs, sockets are streams of events.

Comment: Ahh okay, I think I was misunderstanding. So on the front-end I'll just emit a message saying the user visited that page that my socket can handle, correct?

Comment: Yep on the front-end you choose when to start the connection to your socket server, and then just send the message, make sure you create a Handler on the Back end for listening to that specific message. If you find any difficulties, just create a new question on stackoverflow

Comment: Perfect. Thank you!