# Disconnect the current url of a popup and change to a new url

Tags: javascript, socket.io, popup, window.open

I have a (parent) page which can open a popup by

```
popup = window.open("https://localhost:3000/#/new", "popup", "status=1, location=1, width=1000, height=1200");
```

I have also implemented in the backend (ie, `www`):

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  console.log("LOG: just connected: " + socket.id);
  socket.emit('id', socket.id);
  socket.on('disconnect', function () {
    console.log("LOG: just disconnected: " + socket.id)
  })
})
```

As a result, closing MANUALLY the popup shows `LOG: just disconnected: ...`.

From time to time, the parent page wants to change the url of the popup. If I use `popup.location.href = newUrl`, the popup does load the new page, but it does NOT disconnect the previous url; there is NO `LOG: just disconnected: ...` displayed. And when I close manually the popup, it shows that SEVERAL sockets are disconnected at the same time.

I would prefer the parent page to be able to disconnect the current url of the popup and change to a new url while keep the popup open. Because closing and reopening a popup changes its location/size, this is not what I want.

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parent page can send a `close` message (eg, by `postMessage`) to the child page. Then, on the side of the child page, it can force the disconnection by `disconnect()`.

References: [1](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/issues/47) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5560187/702977).