# I can't disconnect my socket.io test server

Tags: java

I try to disconnect my client:

```
public class SiecZapis {

    public static Socket gniazdo2;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SiecZapis().doIt2();
    }

    public void doIt2() {   
        try {
            ServerSocket gniazdo = new ServerSocket(4242);

            while(true) {
                Socket gniazdo2 = gniazdo.accept();
                PrintWriter pisarz = new PrintWriter(gniazdo2.getOutputStream());
                String porada = "test2";
                pisarz.println(porada);
                pisarz.close();
                System.out.println(porada);
            }
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void exit() {
        gniazdo2.disconnect();
    }
}
```

I tried to use something like `socket.disconnect()` from this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5048231/force-client-disconnect-from-server-with-socket-io-and-nodejs) but there is not method `disconnect` in `socket`.
Could you please advise how to handle this topic?

Comment: Running a Socket in the main thread is a bad idea, make sure that you also handle Nullpointer Exception.

Comment: Java `Socket`s and `socket.io` are two completely different things (in different languages nonetheless). You can't just pick some functions from one of them and try to use them on the other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insted of disconnect try using the close method.

```
public void exit(){
    gniazdo2.close();
}
```

Further reading: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#close--