# how to set max. of clients of socket io?

Tags: javascript, html, socket.io, client-server

to my server are just two clients allowed to connect with. How to set the max of clients on two clients of socket.io?
this is how my server.js looks like:

```
var path = require('path');
var express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    http = require('http'),
    socketIo = require('socket.io');

var server = http.createServer(app);
var io = socketIo.listen(server);
server.listen(9000);

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + 'index.html'));


});
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/'));

io.on('connection', function (socket) {


    socket.on('data', function (data) {


        socket.broadcast.emit('data', data)
    });

    socket.on('disconnect', function () {
console.log("disconnect")
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is untested, but you should be able to check number of users on connection and change it on connect/disconnect.

Here is an example:

```
const connectedUsers = 0;
const maxUsers = 2;
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    if(connectedUsers + 1 > maxUsers){ // check if the new connection will exceed the max connections allowed
       socket.disconnect(); // if so, disconnect the user and exit https://stackoverflow.com/a/5560187/11518920
       return;
    }
    connectedUsers++; // otherwise + 1 to the connectedUsers
    socket.on('data', function (data) {
       socket.broadcast.emit('data', data)
    });
   socket.on('disconnect', function () {
       connecteUsers--; // on a disconnected decrease the connectedUsers count
       console.log("disconnect")
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks, is there any trick how to show an alert to the third user that he cannot connect to the server ?

Comment: @GermanyDeutschland Before calling the disconnect function, just send a message to that specific user.

Comment: Yes but how to send the message ?